# linkedType" not getting while making "MyClass.property.list()" node js, orientjs

Tags: node.js, orientdb, orientjs

when i am trying to get all property of class but not getting "LinkedType"

is it possible to get all property details including "LinkedType" and "LinkedClass"

thank you
Abhishek**strong text**

Comment: my code is here                                                                                                                           MyClass.property.list()
.then(function (properties) {
console.log('The class has the following properties:', properties);
});

Comment: Hi, I have reproduced your problem, could you open an issue on github ?

Comment: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs/issues/186